# Libssh2 compilation using with-libssl-prefix not working

Tags: c, libssh2, libssl

I have downloaded and compiled the latest version of libssl, the result of which is located at /usr/local/ssl. I want to compile libssh2 using the files in this folder, and to do that I've set the switch "--with-libssl-prefix=/usr/local/ssl".

After performing "./configure --with-libssl-prefix=/usr/local/ssl" and "make", the resulting libssh2.so, according to the output of "ldd", depends on the libssl found in the /usr/lib64, which is exactly what I don't want.

What can I do to force libssh2 to be compiled with the libssl I have in /usr/local/ssl?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When compiling a static libssh2 library as i386 it always returns an x86\_64 library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539587/when-compiling-a-static-libssh2-library-as-i386-it-always-returns-an-x86-64-libr)